# handle error during remove record

Tags: java, exception

```
void deleteFilm(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {
     try {
         filmService.deleteFilm(id);
     }
     catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
         throw e;
     }
     catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex) {

     }
}

    2018-08-15 18:12:10.075  WARN 8568 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
2018-08-15 18:12:10.075 ERROR 8568 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`todo`.`seance`, CONSTRAINT `FKchlcmip8ejlfuo4c990k5ry8y` FOREIGN KEY (`film_id`) REFERENCES `film` (`id`))
2018-08-15 18:12:10.077  INFO 8568 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2018-08-15 18:12:10.080 ERROR 8568 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
2018-08-15 18:12:10.154 ERROR 8568 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`todo`.`seance`, CONSTRAINT `FKchlcmip8ejlfuo4c990k5ry8y` FOREIGN KEY (`film_id`) REFERENCES `film` (`id`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

ConstraintViolationException don't catch error and using  SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException i have is never throw by corresponding try block

i read that

```
java.lang.Object
   java.lang.Throwable
      java.lang.Exception
         java.sql.SQLException
            java.sql.SQLNonTransientException
               java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
                  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
```

jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException inherits from SQLEXception but this exception is never throw by try block

Comment: Did you debug and check yourself? Could it be a different package or the exception actually being encapsulated by another exception (like JavaEE wraps a lot of exceptions in `EJBException` and the like)?

Comment: I import org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException;

Comment: Well, that exception is not even in the class hierarchy you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a programming error and has to be corrected by choosing how to handle the foreign key.

The problem is that you're deleting a parent record, leaving orphan entries (`film_id` in `todo.seance`, which references the film ID)

You have two options

- Do cascade deletion, so that if a film is deleted, corresponding `seance` records are also deleted (automatically done by the database). MySQL's documentation on forein keys is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) (with reference options, which include `on delete cascade`, among other things)
- Change application logic to first delete `seance` entries for the `film_id` before deleting the parent film record.

Remember that you need to explicitly throw the exception:

```
catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex) {
    //Assuming deleteFilm() has the correct throws clause
    throw ex; //you are not doing this.
}
```

Comment: My concept is don't using remove casade. If i try delete film first i want catch exception and return some string to front site application. I know that i should first delete seance

Comment: When i try delete film i want display info that i should firstly delete seance

Comment: Check the edit. You are not rethrowing the constraint violation exception. You can also explicitly count child records and manually throw the exception before trying to delete the parent.

Comment: Count child record that is very good idea, ok but ConstraintViolationException is thrown why catch block don't work?

Comment: Did you notice that you are just swallowing the exception? You need to rethrow it.

Comment: How i do that that rethrow it?

Comment: Check the very last part of this answer (the last `catch` block)